# How to customize how neovims "shell command buffer" is shown?

Tags: neovim, buffers, shell

I am wondering about the behavior of the buffer that appears in the bottom of the terminal when running a shell command in neovim.

- How can I make it appear the right side instead?
- How can I make the buffer take half of the screen space?

Here is an example of how it works out of the box:
Write some code
[image: first]
Then after running the code
[image]